# Dificuldade em ajustar menu e footer em layout responsivo

Tags: css, css3, layout-responsivo

O código abaixo diz respeito a *menu* e *footer*, cujo os quais estou com dificuldade em ajustar para layout responsivo:

```css
 /*Código por Domingos Pereira, GPSI12 */
 /*Dísciplina de Redes */
 /* Professor: João Delgado */
 /*
 Menu
 */
#menu{
 text-align:center;
 width:750px;
 margin:0 auto;
 white-space: nowrap;
 display: block;

}
#menu > ul > li.active > a {
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
#menu ul ul li.active > a {
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
#menu ul {
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
 float: left;
 width: 49,5%;
 background-color:#EDEDED;
 list-style:none;
 font:80% Tahoma;
}
#menu ul li { 
 display: inline; 
}
#menu ul li a {
 display:block;
 text-align:center;
 background-color:#EDEDED;
 color: #333;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-bottom:3px solid #EDEDED;
 padding: 2px 10px;
 float:left;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
 background-color:#D6D6D6;
 color: #6D6D6D;
 border-bottom:3px solid #565656;
}
 /* Termina Menu*/
 /* Footer */
footer {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
 background: #e9e9e9;
 margin-top: -28px;
 padding: 48px 0 28px 0;
}
 /* Termina Footer */
 /* Imagens*/
 /* codigo extra, caso necessário */
 /*<img class="responsive" src="http://fotopex.com/42.jpg" />*/
 /*img.responsive { 
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
 margin: 2.5% ;
 }
 @media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
 img.responsive { max-width: 95%; }
 }
 @media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
 img.responsive { max-height: 95%; } */
 /* Fim codigo extra, caso necessário */
 #logo{
 margin-left:10%;
 }
 /* IFRAMES / SLIDE*/
iframe{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 allowfullscreen:true;
 border:none;
 mozallowfullscreen:true;
 webkitallowfullscreen:true;
}
.wrapperr {
 max-width: 65.33333333333333em;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.wrapper         {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
 background:#ffffff;
}
.h_iframe        {position:relative;}
.h_iframe .ratio {display:block;width:100%;height:auto;}
.h_iframe iframe {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%; height:100%;}
 /* Fim Imagens */
 /* Formatação da página */
html, body {
 font-size: 100%; 
 -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; 
 -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; 
 height: 98%;
 background-color:#f9f9f9;
}
#divsec {
 max-width:100%;
 max-height:100%;
 position:relative;
 height: 70%;
 width:60%;
 margin:0 auto;
 text-align:center;
}
#divinicio {
 max-width:100%;
 max-height:100%;
 position:relative;
 height: 65%;
 width:60%;
 border:1px solid #000000;
 margin:0 auto;
 margin-top:4%;
 text-align:center;
}
.container {
 padding: 3em 0;
 -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
 -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
 -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
 -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
}
 /* Fim formatação da página */
 /* Tabela Software */
table {
 position:relative;
 margin-left:0;
 margin-right:0;
 margin-top:1%;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border: 1px solid #666666;
 font: normal 11px verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: #363636;
 background: #f6f6f6;
 text-align:left;
 display:block; 
 width:auto; 
 overflow-x: auto;
}
caption {
 text-align: center;
 font: bold 16px arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
 background: transparent;
 padding:6px 4px 8px 0px;
 color: #CC00FF;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
thead, tfoot {
 background:url(bg1.png) repeat-x;
 text-align:left;
 height:30px;
}
thead th, tfoot th {
 padding:5px;
}
table a {
 color: #333333;
 text-decoration:none;
}
table a:hover {
 text-decoration:underline;
}
tr.odd {
 background: #f1f1f1;
}
tbody th, tbody td {
 padding:5px;
}
hr{
 height:2px; 
 border:1px;
 color:#000; 
 background-color:#000; 
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
 /* Fim tabela software */
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>1CCEPB</title>
 <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
 <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"> </script>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="description" content="Escola Profissional de Braga, EPB,Math,Matemática,Imagem da Matemática" />
</head>
<body>
 <!-- Logotipo -->
 <header>
  <div id="logo">
   <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo_epb.png" alt="EPB" /></a>
  </div>
 </header>
 <!-- FimLogotipo -->
 <!-- Menu Principal -->
 <div class="clear"></div>
 <nav>
  <center>
   <div id="menu">
    <ul>
     <li><a href='index.html'>Inicio</a></li>
     <li><a href="galeria.html">Galeria </a> </li>
     <li><a href="evento.html">Eventos</a></li>
     <li><a href="math.html">Matemática</a></li>
     <li><a href="fq.html">FQ</a></li>
     <li class='active'><a href="software.html">Software</a></li> 
    </ul>
   </div>
  </center>
 </nav> 
 <br>
 <br>
 <br> 
 <!-- Fim Menu Principal -->
 <!-- DIV Software -->
 <div id="divsec">
  <!--Tabela software -->

  <center>
   <table width=500>
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th scope="col">Software</th><th scope="col">Descrição</th><th scope="col">Download</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <th scope="row" id="Graph">
       <hr/>
       <p>Graph 4.4.2</p>
      </th>
      <td>
       <br>
       <p>Programa que desenha o gráfico de uma função e informa sobre algumas das suas caracteristicas.</p>
      </td>
      <td>
       <a href="/software/graph.exe" title="Graph 4.4.2">Download</a>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <th scope="row" id="Graph">
       <hr/>
       <p>FX-9860G Emulator</p>
      </th>
      <td>
       <p>Programa que emula a calculadora gráfica Casio FX - 9860G SD</p>
      </td>
      <td>
       <a href="/software/fx-9869-emulator.exe" title="FX-9860G Emulator">Download</a>
      </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <th scope="row" id="Graph">
      <hr/>
      <p>Função Trignométrica</p>
      </th>
      <td>
      <p>Associação entre o círculo trigonométrico e os gráficos das funções trignoméricas no intervalo [0 , 2PI]</p>
      </td>
      <td>
       <a href="/software/fx-9869-emulator.exe" title="Função Trignométrica">Download</a>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
     <th scope="row" id="Graph">
      <hr/>
      <p>Círculo Trignométrico</p>
     </th>
     <td>
      <p>Programa que permite a introdução do círculo trigonométrico.</p>
     </td>
     <td>
      <a href="/software/fx-9869-emulator.exe" title="Graph">Download</a>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>

    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <th scope="row" id="Graph">
       <hr/>
       <p>Poly32</p>
      </th>
      <td>
       <p>Programa que permite reconhecer e analisar algumas propriedades dos sólidos platónicos.</p>
      </td>
      <td>
       <a href="/software/fx-9869-emulator.exe" title="Graph">Download</a>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <th scope="row" id="Graph">
       <hr/>
       <p>GeoGebra</p>
      </th>
      <td>
       <br>
       <p>Software de matemática dinâmica para utilizar em ambiente de sala de aula, que reune geometria, álgebra e cálculo.</p>
      </td>
      <td>
       <a href="/software/fx-9869-emulator.exe" title="GeoGebra">Download</a>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
   </center>
   <!-- Fim Tabela software -->

 </div>
 <!-- Fim DIV centrada -->
 <!-- Copy rights-->
 <footer>
  <p align="center">Copyright &copy; 2015 All rights reserved | <b> Domingos Manuel Gavina Pereira</b></p>
 </footer>
 <!-- Fim Copy rights-->
</body>
</html>
```

Quando a *viewport* é redimensionada, o *menu* não está responsivo e o *footer* "sobe" e fica centralizado, mesmo utilizando `bottom: 0`.

Como posso resolver esse problema utilizando apenas HTML e CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Existem 2 modos de obter o resultado que você procura.

- Utilizando apenas `css`, porém você fica limitado a uma certa estrutura html/css para fazer funcionar.
- Utilizando javascript (com `css` também), onde você tem uma dinâmica melhor no seu site.

Antes de partir para a resposta propriamente, devo lhe alertar que a sua tabela está com um html confuso. Você não precisa criar uma tag `<tbody>` para cada linha, apenas uma já é suficiente, o `<tr>` já funciona como definição de "linha".

---

### Problema

Agora vamos ao problema, propriamente dito.

#### Footer

O seu problema do `footer` ocorre pois sua `#divsec` está definida com um valor de `height` fixo de 70%, ou seja, ela sempre vai ter 70% da altura da tela, por isso seu `footer` não fica fixo no fim da página. Remova essa propriedade deixando a `#divsec` assim:

```
#divsec {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    position:relative;
    width:60%;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Outra observação, o seu `footer` não irá precisar do `margin-top:-28px;`, a não ser que você realmente precise, mas com isso ele está ficando "por cima" da tabela, então recomendo remover essa propriedade para que ele fique imediatamente abaixo da tabela.

#### Menu

Quanto ao seu menu, é um pouco mais complexo, utilizando apenas `css`, você pode utilizar um `@media` tendo um código semelhante a este:

```
.menu {
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    background:#eee;
    color:000;
}
.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0; padding: 0;
    display: none;
}
.menu ul li {
    display: table-cell;
}
.menu:hover .menu ul {
    display: table;
}
span {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
}
span:hover ~ ul {
    display:table;
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
    .menu {
        width: 50%;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    .menu ul {
        display:table;
        width:100%;
    }
    .menu ul li {
        height:40px;
        line-height:40px;
        text-align:center;
    }
    span {
        display:none;
    }   
}
```

Veja o exemplo funcionando: http://jsfiddle.net/ggxbu8sf/2/

Porém, como dito anteriormente, você fica restrito a uma estrutura de `html`, para que ele tenha a exibição, você deve deixa a tag `ul` logo após a tag `span`, que é onde ativamos a exibição do menu em layout *responsive*.

Já para ter uma funcionalidade mais dinâmica, recomendo que procure por menu em javascript. Existem diversos modelos prontos para usar em `jQuery`, por exemplo.

Mas isso vai depender da sua disponibilidade de criar/utilizar javascript em seu projeto. Como neste caso sua necessidade é de utilizar apenas `html` e `css`, a resposta acima deve servir.
Espero que isso lhe ajude e oriente a obter seus resultados.

Comment: Celsom, talvez seria melhor se você tirasse suas duvidas antes de elaborar sua resposta para evitar conteúdos desnecessários na reposta, para isso e para informar algo ao usuário utilize os campos de comentários. Outro ponto que gostaria de comentar também o o seguinte "Para cada caso usamos uma abordagem diferente, com uma linguagem de programação ideal diferente", apenas javascript pode ser considerado linguagem de programação nesse caso, sendo que HTML é linguagem de marcação e CSS diz respeito a "folha de estilo" em alguns casos também chamado de linguagem de formatação :)

Comment: Sim, talvez o modo como tenha me expressado tenha sido errado. Mas não foi o tipo de pergunta esperando uma resposta, e sim para posteriormente responder ambas no corpo do texto. Pois busquei responder sanando as duas dúvidas, como fazer somente a alteração/função em css e o que deve fazer caso busque a funcionalidade em JS.

Comment: Compreendo, mas sinceramente "Você precisa ajustar apenas o layout?" parece uma pergunta esperando resposta. Entenda Celsom, não estou apontando como uma critica negativa, talvez você poderia usar esse trecho de texto sem a utilização de perguntas como algo desse tipo "caso você precise ajustar apenas o layout e precise que ele fique com o "hamburguer menu" e que ao clicar ele expanda as opções, você pode fazer...", dessa forma você pode evitar que hajam "duvidas" em relação ao motivo das perguntas...

Comment: Sim sim, eu entendo o seu ponto, e pretendo justamente isso, melhorar a explicação. Só não estou no pc agora para fazer com mais facilidade. Mas vou reler e elaborar melhor. Levei como construtiva sim =D

Comment: @DorivalZanetto realmente, lendo com mais calma agora, havia ficado meio confuso a explicação, acho que agora melhorou =D Obrigado pela dica

Answer (score 0):

Sem Javascript fica meio complicado e feio de fazer, pois você não vai conseguir usar o click, só o hover do CSS3.. Você terá de criar dois estilos CSS3 para o menu, um para a versão esktop e outro para a verssão mobile (nesa você determina a partir de qual largura tu deseja alterar para o menu mobile..

Para isso use:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1800px) {  }
```

mude para a quantidade de pixel que tu quer que alterne o menu.. Entre as chaves você vai colocar o estilo do menu (ou do site inteiro, prefiro assim) na sua versão mobile..

use esse video (espanhol) para auxilio :
[Menu Responsivo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EB4BG3QZn3o)

Você só irá precisar alterar, ao ínves de usar o javascript coloque no CSS .menu_bar (classe do menu) :hover e entre chave o padding etc que estão no javascript..

Qualquer dúvida fala aí

EDIT (fiz um exemplo para você)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1800px) {  
    /* Aqui vai a classe do meu menu */
    .menu_bar {
        display:block;
        margin: 0;
        width:100%;
        height: 60px;
        position: fixed;
        top:0;
        background:#889aae;
        left: -100%;
    }
    /* aqui ele vai mover o meu menu (fazendo ele aparecer) quando eu tiver com o mouse na barra de menu */
    .menu_bar:hover{
        left: 0;
    }
    /* Aqui são as opçoes do meu menu */
    header nav {
        margin-top: -8px;
        width: 75%;
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        right:100%;
        overflow: scroll;
    }

    header nav::-webkit-scrollbar{
            display: none;
    }

    header nav ul li {
            height: 50px;
            display: block;
            margin: 15px;
            text-align: left;
    }
}
```

Veja o vídeo para entender melhor, porém em telefone o site ficara meio ruim, daí tenta usar target no lugar de hover...

O footer tu deixa assim que deve dar:

```
footer{
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 10px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

O teu layout está bem feito, teres usado tabelas para criar o corpo da página foi uma mais valia, tendo feito isto, evitaste imensos problemas com o posicionamento. Ainda assim, da forma como posicionaste os elementos, é bem provável que se não usasses uma tabela para conter o corpo, o mesmo iria acontecer naquela zona.

Ao todo existem 4 tipos de posicionamento, sendo eles **static**, **relative**, **absolute**, **fixed**, dentre este, apenas os 2 primeiros fazem parte do posicionamento normal.

## Static

Elementos com a propriedade positon **static**, são organizados de acordo com o fluxo normal do documento, sendo que não podem ser posicionados utilizando propriedades top, left, e outras, ou seja, elas agem de acordo com a estrutura definida para eles no fluxo normal da página. Por padrão, elementos sem propriedade position definida, são **static**.

```css
.cont { background-color:gray; padding:15px; }
.primeiro { background-color:red; top:10px;}
.segundo{ background-color:blue; }
.terceiro{ background-color:orange; }
```

```html
<section class="cont">
<div class="primeiro">Primeiro</div>
<div class="segundo">Segundo</div>
<div class="terceiro">Terceiro</div>
</section>
```

## Relative

Atribuindo o posicionamento **relative** à um elemento, faz com que este seja posicionado relativamente de acordo com a posição normal deste elemento, ou seja, se tivermos um elemento com posicionamento relativo, entre outros com posicionamento estático, o elemento com posicionamento relativo pode assumir novos posicionamentos, e os elementos estáticos nem vão dar por isso, vão agir como se àquele elemento ainda lá estivesse.

```css
.cont { background-color:gray; padding:15px; }
.primeiro { background-color:red; position:relative; top:100px;}
.segundo{ background-color:blue; }
.terceiro{ background-color:orange; }
```

```html
<section class="cont">
<div class="primeiro">Primeiro</div>
<div class="segundo">Segundo</div>
<div class="terceiro">Terceiro</div>
</section>
```

**#Solução:**

O problema existente no teu layout, ocorre devido as medidas especificadas para o tamanho do documento, sendo que estás a trabalhar com uma margem de erro que varia de acordo com o valor da tela, podendo variar de 200~450px de altura *(isto, com base no tamanho da minha tela)*.

```
html, body {
    font-size: 100%; 
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; 
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; 
    height: 98%;
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
}
```

Nesta parte, é onde acontece essa violação. Remova a propriedade `heigth`, para solucionar o problema.

E para o `footer`, remova simplesmente a propriedade `margin-top`, ou mude o valor negativo para um positivo qualquer, dependendo o espaço desejado.

```
footer {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #e9e9e9;
    margin-top: 1em;
    padding: 48px 0 28px 0;
}
```

Neste exemplo acima, troquei o valor `-28px` por `1em`.

Sendo que estás a trabalhar com tabelas, as propriedades `position` dos elementos constituintes da parte principal *(header, container da tabela, footeer)*, poderiam funcionam sem o posicionamento relativo, estas e muitas outras propriedades que estão na folha de estilos, sem desempenhar qualquer função importante.